# lpstringの内容が実際に入力した値とずれる

Tags: c#

easyhookを利用してExtTextOutをフックしました。
実際にコンソールに出力してみるとテキストの内容が実際の入力と29ほどずれてしまいます。
例えばabcと入力するとコンソールにはDEFと表示されます。
なぜなのでしょうか？
フックしている箇所のコードは下記のとおりです。
それ以外の部分は
https://github.com/EasyHook/EasyHook-Tutorials/tree/master/Managed/RemoteFileMonitor
を参考に作成しています。

```
    bool ExtTextOut_Hook(
        IntPtr hdc,
        int x,
        int y,
        uint fuOptions,
        [In] ref RECT lprc,
        string lpString,
        uint cbCount,
        [In] IntPtr lpDx)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (this._messageQueue)
            {
                this._messageQueue.Enqueue(string.format("{0}", lpString);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return ExtTextOutW(
            hdc,
            x,
            y,
            fuOptions,
            ref lprc,
            lpString,
            cbCount,
            lpDx);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

こちらで試したところ問題なくフックできます。
c++ フック対象プロセス(32bit)

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    wchar_t str[] = L"abcdef";
    ::ExtTextOutW(NULL, 0, 0, 0, nullptr, str, _countof(str), nullptr);
    std::string tmp;
    std::getline(std::cin, tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

C# フックDLL
FileMonitorHook/InjectionEntryPoint.cs
への追加コード

```
    public void Run(
        EasyHook.RemoteHooking.IContext context,
        string channelName)
    {
         //省略

         var extextouthook = EasyHook.LocalHook.Create(
            EasyHook.LocalHook.GetProcAddress("gdi32.dll", "ExtTextOutW"),
            new ExtTextOutW_Delegate(ExtTextOutW_Hook),
            this);

         //省略

         extextouthook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new Int32[] { 0 });
         //省略

    }

    //省略

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;

    }
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "ExtTextOutW")]
    static extern bool ExtTextOut(IntPtr hdc, int X, int Y, uint fuOptions,
   [In] ref RECT lprc, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpString,
   uint cbCount, [In] IntPtr lpDx);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    delegate bool ExtTextOutW_Delegate(
        IntPtr hdc,
        int x,
        int y,
        uint options,
        [In] ref RECT lprc,
        string lpString,
        uint c,
        IntPtr lpDx
        );
    bool ExtTextOutW_Hook(
        IntPtr hdc,
        int x,
        int y,
        uint options,
        [In] ref RECT lprc,
        string lpString,
        uint c,
        IntPtr lpDx
        )
    {
        bool result = ExtTextOut(hdc, x, y, options,ref lprc, lpString, c, lpDx);
        try
        {
            lock (this._messageQueue)
            {
                if (this._messageQueue.Count < 1000)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lpString))
                    {

                    }else
                    {
                        string msg = "ExtTextOutW_Hook:" + lpString;
                        this._messageQueue.Enqueue(msg);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        return result;
    }

    //省略
```

"abcdef"
という入力に対して
ExtTextOutW_Hook:abcdef
とコンソールに表示されます。

> 実際にコンソールに出力してみるとテキストの内容が実際の入力と29ほどずれてしまいます。
>   例えばabcと入力するとコンソールにはDEFと表示されます。

「abcと入力すると」というのはExtTextOutWに対して"abc"として引数を渡したのでしょうか？
何か別の操作を行ったように思えます。
そのあたりを詳しく記載したほうが、あなたが何に疑問を持っているか分かると思います。

Comment: 記載していただいたプログラムでも同様でした。具体的にはnotepad.exeを上記のプログラムから起動し、アルファベットをabcと入力すると
ExtTextOutW_Hook:DEF
と出力されてしまいます。

Comment: win10のnotepad.exeで確認してみましたが、ExtTextOutWにはETO_GLYPH_INDEXが指定してコールされているのでlpStringは文字列ではないですよ。

Comment: なるほど。ということはどのような文字列が渡されたかを知ることはできないのでしょうか？

Comment: 渡されたという意味があいまいです。
現在表示されている文字列を取得したいだけであれば、WM_GETTEXTメッセージを送信する方法や、UIAutomationを使う方法もあります。
入力を１個づつ拾いたいのであれば、メッセージフックやキーボードフックを仕掛けることもできます。
文字列が何のAPIに渡されて描画されているのかを知りたいのであればWindbgでデバッグして使用されているAPIを調べる必要があります。

Comment: 対象のアプリ（プライベートなアプリです）をapimonitorで見たところ、現在表示されている文字列はExtTextOutWで描画されているようです。この場合はWM_GETTEXTは使えないですよね？そうした場合、表示されている文字列を取得するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？
Windows プログラミングについてはあまり知識がないのでおかしい質問をしているかもしれません。

Comment: @cwp さん　notepadであればこちらでも調べようがありますが、わたしには「対象のアプリ（プライベートなアプリです）」がどのように作成されているのか不明なため使えるのか使えないのか答えられません。何を対象にするかで方法はいろいろあるんですから、それを教えてもらわないと答えられません。  ExtTextOu‌​tWの引数に文字列が渡されていることが確認できているのであれば、API Hookでいいんじゃないですか？なぜnotepadの話がでてきたんでしょうか？